# Trying to update a single field in a firestore database

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-cloud-firestore

I have a firestore database with the following structure.
[image]

What I want to do is to update the chosen value when the user clicks a button.  I have the new value I want to add, but I am getting errors.

```
 <button className='buttonCheck' onClick={checkAnswer}>CHECK MY ANSWER</button>
```

when I click the button it calls the "checkAnswer" function

```
function AnswerComponent(props) {
  let totalNoAnswers = props.totalAnswers;
  let answers = props.answersarray; 
  
  const [valueA, setValue] = useState() // make this mean something better
  const [showCongratsModal, setShowCongratsModal] = useState(false);
  const [showCongratsURL, setShowCongratsURL] = useState("")
  const [showWindowContent, setShowWindowContent] = useState("")
  const [selectedAnswerGroup, setSelectedAnswerGroup] = useState("")
  const [chosenCount, setChosenCount]= useState()

  function checkAnswer() {   
    setShowCongratsModal(true)
    if (valueA === true) {
      setShowCongratsURL("https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/assignment219000170.appspot.com/o/videos%2Fcongrat_w3_s.mp4?alt=media&token=034ea1bc-b3e0-4b51-957f-854dae963896")
    } else if (valueA === false) {
      setShowWindowContent("Incorrect answer - please try again.")            
    } else {
      setShowWindowContent("Please choose an answer before proceeding.")            
    }

    const updateFirestore = async () => {
      const db = firebase.firestore();      
      const collectionId = "Questions";
      const documentId = "balances";
    
      const snapshot = db.collection(collectionId).doc(documentId);
      console.log("> ", snapshot)
      console.log(">> ", selectedAnswerGroup)

      const res = await snapshot.set({      
        balances: {
          balances: {
            answers: {
              [selectedAnswerGroup]: {
                chosen: chosenCount
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }, {merge: true})
    console.log("1", res)
    }
    updateFirestore()
    
  }
```

The variable selectedAnswerGroup contains "answer_1" - and "chosenCount" will contain a new number, so using the above, I thought I would update the database.

However,I get an error on the console
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: firestore.collection(...).doc(...).balances is undefined

I can't see what I have done wrong.

Do I need to contain this in a firebase.auth() block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting this error: `TypeError: firestore.collection(...).doc(...).balances is undefined` because of the way you construct your reference.
This is the line of code you're having an error:

```
const snapshot = await firestore.collection(collectionId).doc(documentId).balances.balances.answers[selectedAnswerGroup]
```

`TypeError: undefined` occurs when a property is read or a function is called on an undefined variable. You're using a dot notation to access  a `method` so it reads `balances` as a method.

Your reference should always be following this pattern:

```
db.collection("main_collection").doc("main_collection's_document").collection("sub_collection").doc("sub_collection's_document");
```

Checkout [**Cloud Firestore Data model**](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/data-model), this is a good way to start building a reference to your Firestore Data Structure.

For you to update a specific field inside the map of an object, you have to define the document identifier and build a map based on your Firestore Data Structure. See code below:

```
function checkAnswer() {
    setShowCongratsModal(true)
    if (valueA === true) {
      setShowCongratsURL("https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/assignment219000170.appspot.com/o/videos%2Fcongrat_w3_s.mp4?alt=media&token=034ea1bc-b3e0-4b51-957f-854dae963896")
    } else if (valueA === false) {
      setShowWindowContent("Incorrect answer - please try again.")            
    } else {
      setShowWindowContent("Please choose an answer before proceeding.")            
    }
    
    updateFirestore()
    .then((snapshot) => {
        console.log('updateFirestore() successfully called!');
        console.log(snapshot);
    })
    .catch((e) => {
        console.log(e);
    });
}

async function updateFirestore() {
    const db = firebase.firestore();   
    const collectionId = "Questions";
    const documentId = "balances";
    
    // You could also log something here to ensure that this async function has been ran.
    // console.log(selectedAnswerGroup);
    // console.log(chosenCount);

    const snapshot = db
    .collection(collectionId)
    .doc(documentId)
    .set(
    {      
        balances: {
            balances: {
                answers: {
                    [selectedAnswerGroup]: {
                        chosen: chosenCount
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }, {merge: true});

    return snapshot;
}
```

You may check [**Set a document**](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#set_a_document) and [**Update fields in nested objects**](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_fields_in_nested_objects) documentations for more information.

Comment: thank you for a really good answer.  I wish I could say it worked but still having some issues.  I modified the code (which could be the issue) but now, I do not get any error (but the value is not updated in firestore) - I've added a console.log to the "res" and now getting an undefined.

Comment: Hi @Joseph, can you please include on your question any stacktrace and printed logs on your console so that we can reproduce the error that you're encountering. I can verify that the answer posted above is working on my end and not having any errors.

Comment: There was no errors - just nothing.  I also checked to see if there were console errors in firestore, but nothing

Comment: Hi @Joseph, I've updated the code from my answer. Could you please use that code and give us the result, even the console logs.

Comment: I’ll give it a try when I am home and update you

Comment: I am such a fool!  I still had no updates when I used your code, even though the console log said "document successfully written!" so I was stumped until I realised my huge mistake.  I never incremented the count.   Now I see updates.  I have a further issue where I can only update a record once, but this is progress

Comment: Do you have any idea why the document would only update on the first click?

Comment: @Joseph Glad to see it working! For better code structure i would suggest to move the async function outside your function and put some `console.log` to check if the async function has been triggered. I've updated my answer for you.

Comment: the console.log for snapshot always returns undefined (but the database is updating) - I don't know why.  I think I know why it appears to not be working on a second press - I am not updating the counts, so if the page started as count 1, then I updated to 2.  When I try to update again, it doesn't get set to 3, but is overwritten with 2 again